# How you can add an application to the app share list in react-native?

Tags: react-native

How you can add an application to the app share list in react-native?

Comment: Do you mean sharing your content and it's link over whatsapp, twitter and etc.?

Comment: No. I mean to share content from outside app in the app.

Answer (score 1):

This is the module you are looking for
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-share-menu